# SQL Polygon - Max longditudinal distance

Tags: sql-server, geometry, polygon

In SQL Server 2017, I have millions of polygon shapes in a column of a table, I'm trying to work out a way to efficiently calculate the max longitudinal distance (y) of each polygon and the latitude (x) at which it occurs, note I also need this to work with the geometry data type.

e.g. Say I have a polygon of a country like Australia (or any other solid polygon) and I wanted to identify length (y) of the red line in the image below whilst also determining the latitude (x) at which this max distance occurs. Sorry to those in Tasmania I'm going to ignore you in this case :)

[Polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59AOR.png)

Is there a more elegant solution than creating a `CTE` that goes through all possible latitude values (x) in tiny increments between the min and max points of the polygons envelope (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e073de05-463f-4674-9e9f-ff3c67f68b89/how-to-get-the-max-and-min-lattitude-and-longitude-of-a-polygon?forum=sqlspatial) and then returning max from that?

Another example:
With the polygon below I'd be looking to return an x value of around 0.5 and a y value of 0.25.

```
DECLARE @b geometry
SET @b = geometry::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0.1 0.01, 0.2 0.04, 0.3 0.09, 0.4 0.16, 0.5 0.25, 0.6 0.36, 0.7 0.49, 0.8 0.64, 0.9 0.81, 1 1, 
0.9 0.9, 0.8 0.8, 0.7 0.7, 0.6 0.6, 0.5 0.5, 0.4 0.4, 0.3 0.3, 0.2 0.2, 0.1 0.1, 0 0))', 4326)

SELECT @b
```

Would any mathematics's like in the link below help? or only for simple shapes?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLjfReUqj0c
[image]

Comment: That's an interesting problem! I don't think that the envelope method that you mention will work since the max(lat, long) and min(lat, long) may not be on the same meridian (it looks like they are for Australia, but imagine a parallelogram; the envelope is going to be some sort of rectangle). I think the sweep line method is going to be best (if slow). If I may ask, what problem requires you to know this info?